# When to give up on math?

Tags: learning

How do I know when I should give up on math? I can't pass any of my math tests no matter much I study, I have tutors, attend office hours and I still can't do better than a D on any test. Most of the advice I hear is take the class two or three times which is ridiculous to me. It just seems that I am not good at math for whatever reason. I put at least 15 hours a week into math studies outside of class and this is only an entry level college algebra class.

I was planning on an engineering degree because I don't know how to pick a major other than picking one so I need math.

Comment: Adam, this type of question is very difficult to answer, especially when we do not know you. Any response may cause you hurt, and no one wants to do that. There are majors that do not need math.

Comment: And about retaking a class, I think that is terrible advice, there are better ways to go about trying to pass a class.

Comment: I really don't care about "hurt feelings" my feelings don't get hurt, I just need to figure this out. I have no idea what to major in and I had planned on engineering or science for years and I found out I am not  good at math even when I try so I don't know if I should give up or keep going.

Comment: Firstly, I do not believe that you are not good at math. And since you have your sight set on a science major, the hard truth is that mathematics is necessary.

Comment: In addition to tutors, this site is an excellent resource. Post questions you need help/clarification with, and seek useful and helpful answers. There are additional resources online for more practice.

Comment: I am not set on science really, I just had to pick something and though that fit. I have no idea how picking a major is suppose to work so I just did it. But I am guessing this kind of talk will get this locked so I will stay on the math topic. I never tried in high school so I don't think that is a measure of my math abilities, I did terribly but that should be expected when I slept in class and never once did homework. I always assumed math was taught for you to not understand the math but to just memorize processes and I always asked too many why questions.

Comment: Other than math, what classes are you taking, and how are those classes going for you? This may seem off topic, but will allow people to gauge your level.

Comment: Chemistry which I am not enjoying but I am going to get a C+/B- in, political science which I enjoy and have 100 percent in. I don't do any homework for the class so it is quite easy, same with English, I have maybe an hour of homework a week and I enjoy it. Oh and chemistry lab which I do enjoy, have probably an A-/B+ in that.

Comment: To make myself clear, I don't know what I am good at or what I enjoy. Obviously I have hobbies and interests, but don't worry they aren't job/college applicable. What am I suppose to pick for a major? How do I know if I am good at something or not? How much effort and time do I need to put into something before I know that I am not good at it? These are things that I just don't get, I could take this class 3 times to pass it, then move on to the next one and take that 3 times to pass it but I doubt that would be helpful. Maybe I am just not smart enough for math?

Comment: Adam, if you are looking for someone to confirm with you not to continue math, this is not the right place for that.

Comment: No I am just wondering how to know if I am good at math or not?

Comment: As mentioned before, that is very hard to answer. By the way, who gave you the advice of retaking classes multiple times? I am worried you are looking for the answers in the wrong place. At best, this site will direct you to a better source for you.

Comment: It was a math forum, they said many people don't get it the first time and need to take it a couple times for it to "click" then they go on and do well. didn't make sense to me.

Comment: They were NOT referring to taking the class multiple times. They were probably talking about learning a concept. I suggest you update this information in the question, and I also suggest you give some questions you found difficult and if you can, why. Someone will be able to assist you a lot better then.

Comment: I have learned this one twice but never remember how to do it 2^(x-1)=5^(x-3) can't remember the numbers in the exponents but it was similar to that.

Comment: Can you post that in the question? change the question by clicking edit.

Comment: @Adam: Some of your questions are too broad to answer, especially for people who don't know you. "How do I know if I am good at something or not?" Depends on your perceptions; "How do I know when to give up?" Well, depends: if it's something you *need*, then don't give up; if it's something you are doing for enjoyment's sake, then stop when you stop enjoying it. But really, while we can easily help you with specific mathematical problems, the broader philosophical questions are not something that can be discussed here. We are likely to do more harm than good if we attempt armchair psychiatry.

Comment: @Adam: For that question, use logarithms.

Comment: Well I need a major and I picked engineering and I need to take this class.

Comment: @Adam: The folks at Math.SE will do the best to aid your learning in your algebra class, but we cannot answer the broader questions, not unless we know you personally.

Comment: @Adam: in addition to not being able to help you, I think you should ignore any advice given here.. It could as mentioned before,do more harm than good.

Comment: @Adam: Here is a story of a man who had much difficulties with mathematics, but now is physics researcher. http://www.deepastronomy.com/how-i-overcame-my-math-blocks.html

Comment: @Adam: You say you enjoy the Political Science and English courses?  Sounds like you are more geared for humanities and the arts.  Some people do have naturally poor grasp of maths, it isn't for everyone - try taking another major; why do you need to do college at all, you do not seem to have a purpose for it?

Comment: @Lovre: That's a wonderful story there, but if I may: that is a man with a passion, and that passion was what eventually drove him forward to his dream. It seems that Adam is lacking in passion. Or isn't he?

Comment: @Ras: A competent (math) teacher can stir the passions of any student. Students don't lack passion. Rather, they lack teachers competent enough to stir those passions.

Comment: @Bill: Maybe, but in the story, no teacher helped trigger the student, it was his own short-lived passion for computers that drove him to improve his math skills without him realizing. Maybe it's the word "math" on which people are blocking. ;)

Comment: @Adam You don't need a major yet. That is, you don't yet need to commit to anything immediately. Select classes that sound INTERESTING to you. Arrange to meet with professors who are enthusiastic and ask what X major is all about and what careers in that field may be like. Nobody expects you to know your life path at this point. IMO, you sound like you're at a point in life where exploring your possibilities should be at the forefront.

Comment: Hello Adam; just out of curiosity, how did the whole thing play out? Did you stick with a science major?

Answer (score 11):

1. You should be aware that 15 hours per week is *not* a lot when you missed out on math during all your high school time. Just imagine that other students put in, say, 5-10 hours per week during their high school years and that you have to make up for this lost time. It will take a year of working 15 hours per week to just be at their starting level, but unfortunately, it is not clear that you are trying to plug the holes in your knowledge before building on it. Why do you expect to be at the same level as students who actually learned something during high school?
2. For me, the red flag in your post is not that you get a D, but that you do not seem to know before the test that you have not properly learned the content of the course. Did you feel that you had understood the course before the test? If yes, did you discuss with your tutors/professors where your self-assessment goes so wrong? If no, well, what is it that you do not understand and why don't you give us a concrete example.
3. Another possibility of course, is that you understand mathematics, but have legasthenic-like problems with calculations, but I guess that you would have mentioned if you tend to interchange digits or have trouble with basic arithmetic

My suggestions:
a. Look at a site like Alcumus to practice some basics
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Alcumus/Introduction.php
(Note that not all of the problems there are simple but many are and they come with difficulty levels.)

b. Try to pinpoint your problem and ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the only one that can answer as to when to give up on math is you yourself. We will have incomplete information regarding your abilities, and most importantly your passion.

With that said, I, personally, don't think you should give up. People will be glad to answer your questions regarding problems you have. It can never be guaranteed that you will pass exams with perfect marks, or at all. But if you really love mathematics, or engineering for that matter, try to do it! If it won't work out at all, at least you will have tried. Giving up a passion is such a shame.

And of course there's always the hard decision as to what to do to get a job after your exam. I have no answers on this to give you, and I don't think anyone here will have one either. It's up to you what to do, does this make you happy? Do you think you can get a career you will be satisfied with?

Ask questions here and we will do our best to help you!